How can i use partial keys to generate a bitcoin wallet?
The SEEDCARD project is a new approach to creating Bitcoin keys for use in a physical bitcoin card. Below is a diagram to show how the wallet generation software works on two SeedSigner devices:

My main concern is to understand if it is possible to use eliptic curve cryptography to combine private and public partial keys - generated on two separate devices.
I recieved an email from Greg Walker who explained the steps:
"This looks possible.
You can add two private keys together, and the public key for that the same as if you added the two public keys for those private keys together.
Here's an example based on your diagram:
Private Key 1 = 5f2b5383d7ac8d05eb37fb636476a71b5b0af1b2261c2105ece2edc09da3c4fe
Public Key 1 = 02e526ffa1ffce8c47babddb01240c2373e2ad65195543b15377d2918d32d2af69
Private Key 2 = 4de9ec9c3766c7230ccfe12ae8230547dbfb755ae148624f88831d6cd1893608
Public Key 2 = 0313fa7838307dbed5625f997a20ddea16efab775ce206d00dce84183ce02ea900
If you combine these two private keys together, you get the following full private key and full public key:
Private Key 1 + Private Key 2 = ad1540200f135428f807dc8e4c99ac633706670d0764835575660b2d6f2cfb06
Full Public Key = 033b7287de5731320a35018584b0e5700f50a053cd3d86dbf77cad16864ff5101f
You can also add the two original public keys together on their own (without needing the private keys) to get the same full public key:
Public Key 1 + Public Key 2 = 033b7287de5731320a35018584b0e5700f50a053cd3d86dbf77cad16864ff5101f
So you can generate the full public key without knowing the private keys, but you need both of the private keys to be able to spend from this full public key."
Before i go ahead and start to find a developer to code this, i would appeciate any comments or feedback.
SEEDCARD website on Github - https://seedcard.github.io/website/index.html

You've re-invented threshold signing, but without its main advantage.
There is a keypair $(k, k G)$ whose secret key $k$ is additively shared $k = k_1 + k_2$, with each device holding one of the shares.
To sign with the keypair, it is necessary to have access to both shares.
It is safe to generate $k_1$ and $k_2$ independently, to result in a random combined key $k = k_1+k_2$.
It is also correct that private keys and public keys are additively homomorphic (when using additive group notation): $k G = k_1 G + k_2 G$.
But your solution for signing is to simply reconstruct $k$ in one place and use it to sign as normal.
True threshold schemes generate signatures using an interactive protocol, in such a way that $k$ is never reconstructed in a single place.
This is their main advantage!
Threshold signature solutions are incredibly common in the blockchain landscape, so it's not clear what advantage your approach has.
